# Inserting a node in an xml file

Tags: java, xml, dom, insert

I would like to insert a node in an xml file using Java DOM. I am actually editing a lot of contents of a dummy file in order to mofidy it like the original.

I would want to add an open node and close node in between the following file;

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <Memory xmlns:xyz="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
            xmlns:abc="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Derivative="ABC"            
            xmlns="http://..">

       ///////////<Address> ///////////(which I would like to insert)

            <Block ---------
            --------
            -------
            />

      ////////// </Address> /////////(which I would like to insert)

            <Parameters Thread ="yyyy" />
            </Memory>
```

I hereby request you to let me know how to I insert  --  in between the xml file?

Thanks in advance.!

What I have tried doing is;

```
            Element child = doc.createElement("Address");
    child.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("Block"));
    root.appendChild(child);
```

But this gives me an output like;

```
        <Address> Block </Address> and not the way i expect :(
```

And now, what I have tried is to add these lines;

```
            Element cd = doc.createElement("Address");
            Node Block = root.getFirstChild().getNextSibling();
        cd.appendChild(Block);
        root.insertBefore(cd, root.getFirstChild());
```

But still, this is not the output which i am looking for. I got this output as 
               ---------

Comment: Your approach is the right one, but a text node is just a text node... try [createElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#createElement(java.lang.String))

Comment: If i try create element, the element just gets created. But I need to mention that the element should be created before the "Block", so how should i specify that?

Comment: BCoz, I already have all the info under "Block" ready, I just have to add the tag "Address" in front of it and after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
DocumentBuilder b = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = b.parse(...);

// Parent of existing Block elements and new Address elemet
// Might be retrieved differently depending on 
// actual structure
Element parent = document.getDocumentElement();
Element address = document.createElement("address");

NodeList nl = parent.getElementsByTagName("Block");
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); ++i) {
    Element block = (Element) nl.item(i);
    if (i == 0)
        parent.insertBefore(address, block);
    parent.removeChild(block);
    address.appendChild(block);
}

// UPDATE: how to pretty print

LSSerializer serializer = 
    ((DOMImplementationLS)document.getImplementation()).createLSSerializer();
serializer.getDomConfig().setParameter("format-pretty-print", Boolean.TRUE);
LSOutput output = 
    ((DOMImplementationLS)document.getImplementation()).createLSOutput();
output.setByteStream(System.out);
serializer.write(document, output);
```

Comment: The output comes out in a single line. Can you tell me how do i use a line separator in this case? Should it be '\n' ?

Comment: Well, this code will not take white space into consideration. How do you output the document? Are you using LSSerializer?

Comment: No. I am not using one. Should I use a serializer? Currently I am just getting out the file using FileOutputStream.

Comment: @dmurali See updated code sample for how to pretty print the document.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is probably:

```
Node parent = block.getParentNode()
Node blockRemoved = parent.removeChild(block);
// Create address
parent.appendChild(address);
address.appendChild(blockRemoved);
```

This is the standard way to re-attach a node in another place under W3C DOM.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for our suggestion. But m doubt is now when I initialize 'address' and 'block'; am i supposed to give "Node Block = root.getFirstChild()" && "Node address = root.getLastChild().getPreviousSibling()" ?

Comment: You you get the original block element using the code you posted, but you should create the new address element using `createElement()`.

Comment: This leaves me again with the same output which I have posted above :(

Comment: I expect "address" to come in between "block", but the output which i am getting leaves me with "address" to come at the end, just before the "block"

Comment: Let me try again: you get the block `Node block = root.getFirstChild()`; remove it from the DOM: `Node parent = block.getParentNode(); Node blockRemoved = parent.removeChild(block);`; create the address element: `Element address = doc.createElement("Address");`; and finally append everything: `parent.appendChild(address); address.appendChild(blockRemoved);`. I.e. you should append the removed block to address, not to its parent and make sure you have actually removed it!

Comment: The output is so strange, I dont know why. I get an output with the open tag and close tag of "address" after the block and before the end :(

Comment: It's a bit hard for me to imagine how that is the case. Could you post your actual code and the actual input and output files? You can remove the contents, but make sure the element structure is the same.

Comment: I have added my original file to my post..!

Comment: I have added my ouput as well :)

Comment: I hope i am being clear enough with my doubt or do I have to add up anything else?

Comment: Since you have multiple `<block>`s, you have to remove them and insert them to address one by one. I.e. you should insert one address element first, and them "move" all the `<block>`s into it. The `getElementsByTagName()` function can help you get all the `<block>`s in one call and you'll just have to interate through the returned list and do the remove and append.

Comment: I just found out that getElementsByTagName() cannot be used since it accepts only a stringValue. But in our case, we dont have a String as we cannot covert the type of Node to a String :(

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the W3C DOM (e.g. http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html ). If so try

```
insertBefore(address, block);
```

Comment: :thanks for your reply.. but can i know what this (address, block) refers to ?

Comment: Made a change in what I have tried now.kindly refer to the code in my post.